# Canceled request issue with document/redirect in chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am facing a issue with my browser (i.e. Chrome) **cancelling the request**. I am not sure why this is happening.

Basically, I have an SPA located at: `http://localhost:4200/` trying to perform a **document/redirect** to `http://localhost:8080/` (I have just included the base URLs here).

[image: screen capture]

What is strange is that the same configuration from `http://localhost:8080` allows a document/redirect from this URL: `https://www.keycloak.org/app/`. See screen capture below:

[image]

I just don't understand why `https://www.keycloak.org/app/` performs the redirect OK and not my SPA at `http://localhost:4200`...

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hello Sideshowbarker, I noticed you mentioned that CORS never causes a request to be canceled. That is interesting. Do you have any idea where else I could look for the cause of this canceled request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find out why the request was canceled by chrome.

I had the following link:

```
<a href="" (click)="logout()">logout from private</a>
```

My angular `(click)="` event was canceled by the `href=""` event.

By replacing the code above with this:

```
<a (click)="logout()">logout from private</a>
```

...the request is no longer canceled.

Thanks to Sideshowbarker for pointing me to right direction.